# angular 2 - form submit null value in the second time

Tags: angular

```
@Component({

    template: `
        <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
            <textarea name="detail" id="detail" formControlName="detail"></textarea>
            <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls['detail'].dirty && formGroup.controls['detail'].invalid">This is required</div>
            <button type="submit" >Post</button>
        </form>
    `,

})
export class CreateDiscussionComponent {
    formGroup: FormGroup;
    submitted: boolean = false;
    constructor(
    ) {
        this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
            detail: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2) ]),
            type : new FormControl('discussion'),
            userPosts: new FormControl([])
        });
    }
    onSubmit(): void {
        console.log('form data', this.formGroup.value)
        this.submitted = true;
        this.formGroup.reset()
    }
}
```

With this code. when I submit form the first time I got this object in the console

```
{
   detai: 'my text'
   type: 'discusion'
   userPosts: []
}
```

The second time and every time after I got this

```
{
   detai: 'my text'
   type: null
   userPosts: null
}
```

I was expecting `type = discussion` and `userposts = []`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

reset method of the FormGroup does not reset the values to your predefined values, it resets to null and reset the statuses(pristine, untouched). To reset status with predefined value you have to set the values again like this:

```
this.form.reset({
  type: 'discussion',
  userPosts: []
});
```

Ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#reset-anchor